# Can't navigate to HangFire Dashboard from deployed blazor wasm app

Tags: blazor-webassembly, hangfire

I have asp.net hosted blazor wasm app that uses hangfire. I have the dashboard configured on the URL "/hangfire" with custom filter that analyzes an access token passed via a query parameter. Here is the related configure part from the startup:

```
        endpoints.MapHangfireDashboard(
            pattern: "/hangfire",
            options: new() { DashboardTitle = "Job Dashboard", Authorization = new[] { new HangFireAuthorizationFilter() } });
```

This works as long as I'm testing locally. When I deploy and I try to navigate to the dashboard via the navigation manager I geta 404:

```
    var accessToken = await LocalStorageService.GetItemAsync<string>(StorageConstants.AUTH_TOKEN);
    NavigationManager.NavigateTo($"/hangfire?token={accessToken}", forceLoad: true);
```

When I copy the URL and paste it in a new InPrivate tab it works as expected. For me it sounds like the Router catches the request and redirects to `NotFound` despite the forceLoad parameter being set to true. Is there any way how I can prevent that?